# How to use PHPGraphLib with Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, phpgraphlib

Please someone give me a very detailed tutorial how to use PHPGraphLib with Codeigniter.

I have tried to use but it did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of initializing a PHPGraphLib inside a Codeigniter controller.

```
<?php 
function barras() {
    $this->load->library('phpgraphlib');
    $graph = new PHPGraphLib(350,200);
    for ($j=1;$j<=$total;$j++) {
                $graph->addData($data[$j]);
    }        
        $graph->setBars(false);
        $graph->setLine(true);
        $graph->setDataPoints(true);
        $graph->setTitle('Menciones por Canal dentro de : '.utf8_decode($camp).'');
        $graph->setLineColor("#FF0000", "#1D669D","#E7DE1D","#AB9999","#002102","#BBDDFF","#D91012","#ABB291","#CC0022","#DD9922","#AB2211");
        $graph->setDataPoints(false);
        $graph->setDataPointColor('maroon');
        $graph->setDataValueColor('maroon');
        $graph->setGoalLine(.0025);
        $graph->setGoalLineColor('red');
        $graph->createGraph();
}
?>
```

Be sure to upload phpgraphlib inside you application/libraries folder
Link to the [Github library](https://github.com/elliottb/phpgraphlib)

Comment: How can I pass the created picture to my view?

Comment: $data['variable'] = $graph->createGraph();
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
in the view file print_r($variable);